# How to understand the method of `ApplicationClassloaderState#hashCode`?

Tags: playframework-1.x

When I read the source of play framework 1.2.5, I found this class:

```
package play.classloading;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

/**
 * Each unique instance of this class represent a State of the ApplicationClassloader.
 * When some classes is reloaded, them the ApplicationClassloader get a new state.
 * <p/>
 * This makes it easy for other parts of Play to cache stuff based on the
 * the current State of the ApplicationClassloader..
 * <p/>
 * They can store the reference to the current state, then later, before reading from cache,
 * they could check if the state of the ApplicationClassloader has changed..
 */
public class ApplicationClassloaderState {
    private static AtomicLong nextStateValue = new AtomicLong();

    private final long currentStateValue = nextStateValue.getAndIncrement();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ApplicationClassloaderState that = (ApplicationClassloaderState) o;

        if (currentStateValue != that.currentStateValue) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (currentStateValue ^ (currentStateValue >>> 32));
    }
}
```

I don't understand the `hashCode` method, why it uses this implementation:

```
return (int) (currentStateValue ^ (currentStateValue >>> 32));
```

The source url:  https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/classloading/ApplicationClassloaderState.java#L34

Answer (score 0):

hashCode() must return an int by design. currentStateValue is a long number denoting the internal state change of the ApplicationClassloader. The play! framework is a sophisticated web framework with a so called hot-code replacement and reload feature. central part of this feature implementation is play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.detectChanges().
As you can see, there are lots of 'new ApplicationClassloaderState()' invocations which means a (fast - depending on your developement workflow and application size) increasing currentStateValue member in the returned object.

**returning to the question: the implementations goal should be to hold the maximum information to differentiate at least 2 different states from each other.**

try to understand currentStateValue as a (encryption)key which encrypts itself (in kryptology terms a terrible approach) but in this context it is very useful.
perhaps you recognize the relationship.
sorry that i cant post links here but you can find some usefull hints in wikipedia searching for "Involution_%28mathematics%29", "One-time_pad", "Tabula_recta".